# Solve $\frac{dT}{dx} +aT =0$ in distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Find all distribution solution to the equation

$$\frac{dT}{dx} + aT =0 $$
$a\in \mathbb{R}$.

How can I do these type of problems in distribution theory. I have no idea on how to start. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the derivative of $e^{ax}T$, as the exponential function is a smooth function, this product is defined for distributions.

Comment: In other words: multiply the equation with the integrating factor $e^{ax}$ and then rewrite the left hand side as a derivative.

Comment: So if I take $f=e^{-ax}$, then clearly $T_{f}$ satisfies the equation. But I donot understand what should be the claim now?

Comment: ok I think I got it. $\frac{d}{dx}(e^{ax}T)$=0, so $e^{ax}T=T_{c}$

Comment: Yes, $f=c·e^{-ax}$. It just shows that regular ODE do not have more solutions in distribution space (if they can be interpreted as equations for distributions first).